# Google Chrome does not keep cookies.

Tags: google-chrome, cookie

There have been a number of users reporting this starting as early as google chrome 11.0.696 on Lucid Lynx. I am seeing it currently on chrome version 16.0.912.75 (Official Build 116452) on Oneiric Ocelot.

Despite having the cookies setting set to allow all cookies, and the "clear cookies on shutdown" option unchecked, All cookies (and sessions that rely on cookies to be persistent) are cleared. This makes using the browser very tedious if you (like me) shut down the browser at the end of the day.

I am currently looking into the 'bug' status of this; However if there is a workaround I can apply in the mean time that would be great! Or if anyone has any further information as to the cause of this bug (I am aware not all users are victim to this behaviour).

To better explain the issue I have created a small video (don't mind the slow internet connection) which can be seen [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cAviDUIv1bg)

Comment: This might be obvious, but I thought I'd better rule it out anyway: Are you sure that the sites you're logging in to are using persistent cookies, not session cookies?

Comment: @Scott Severance Yeah, I've tested on sites that I am in control of.

Comment: I am also victim of this bug. I can also verify that sites i'm in control of using persistent cookies are not being remembered. Furthermore if you open the "Cookies and Other Data" page you will see the list of cookies is cleared between browser sessions.

Comment: @Tchalvak I don't know if you are still watching this Question, however I hope my solution helps you as well.

Comment: @Tchalvak how are you coming with this? Can one of the answers below be accepted now?

Comment: Heh, I actually switched to firefox due to an unrelated issue.  I guess I can simply accept your answer since it's highest voted, although I haven't had time to extensively check the fix.  *shrugs*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is to remove chrome, including it's cache and config directories. 
To do this type the following from the terminal.

`sudo apt-get remove google-chrome-stable` (beta, dev, ect) *un-install chrome*

`rm -rf ~/.cache/google-chrome* ~/.config/google-chrome*` *remove the cache and config directories*

this will also remove the *rouge* folder... 
`~/.config/google-chromed/` (not sure where this came from... but I had to remove it)
*I have a suspicion this is the culprit, however I cannot figure out where it came from or what it's purpose was.*

then re-install chrome and you're set: `sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable`

**WARNING: It is highly recommended that you sync your browser with a google account, or at the very least you backup your preferences before you wipe away your browser like that.**

Answer (score 4):

Check if you have "Allow local data to be set" selected. To access the option, Preferences > Under the hood > Content settings > Cookies.

[image]

Comment: yes that is set. all applicable settings are set to allow this information to be saved.

Answer (score 2):

I found that the *Date modified* of my Chrome Cookies file is a few months behind. So I presume that this SQLite3 database may be crashed or something.

I just removed the file `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Cookies` and restarted Chrome browser. This recreated the 'Cookies' file again and now the Google Chrome does keep cookies. Also make sure that [answer by jokerdino](https://askubuntu.com/a/96669/25798) is carried out.

Comment: My file was about 45 minutes in the future, but I had the same problem.  Deleting the Cookies and Cookies-journal files and then restarting also fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I could solve it only by removing the cache folder and starting google-chrome again (Not even loosing the config data)

`rm -rf ~/.cache/google-chrome*`

I had a similar issue where cookies where not kept and chrome had issues logging me in and asking to login again (Not only websites, but google-chrome profile too!).

Credits to @rlemon solution, I just didn't have to do the rest, this was enough.