# Google Chrome personal data loss after every reboot

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, raid, data-corruption, user-data

After every reboot Chrome asks me to login again. Besides chrome asking me to login, I also have to enter Facebook 2-way code again (As if every time were my first time logging in from this Computer). I also experienced similar issues on different sites where every time I visit (After a reboot) it seems to be the first time doing so from this computer (When it actually isn't).

This Desktop Computer where I recently installed Desktop Ubuntu 16.04 has 2 128gb Raid-0 Vertex-4 SSDs.
Maybe the Raid-0 has something to do with it?

I used to use Windows only on this desktop computer and Ubuntu on my laptop computer (Where Ubuntu 16.04 has worked perfectly for months by the way), decided to get rid of windows and install Ubuntu on my desktop computer as well, I did a regular installation with the same USB flash drive I used for my laptop months before.

I tried uninstalling Chrome so far (First time it was installed via the official downloaded .deb file using GDebi package manager. I removed it using the same package manager and installed it through apt-get this time, but same results).

Any hints on what should I test to find out what's going on would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This recently started happening to me on Ubuntu 14 on my laptop and Ubuntu 16 on my desktop, so I believe it's a problem with chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone having this issue, I found a solution that included uninstalling chrome, manually removing cache and config folders and then reinstall chrome.

It fixed my issue, but later it broke once again and I could solve it by only removing the cache folder:

`rm -rf ~/.cache/google-chrome*`

For original solution see https://askubuntu.com/a/96826/614129

Answer (score 0):

you mean Chromium, don't you?
To find out the ground of your problem, I suggest you to create another user, let's say you usually log in as "peter" and you create "peter1".
If all works fine when you log in as "peter1", it is surely a problem related to configuration files. They seems to be in:
 /home/peter/.config/chromium/ 
 
Maybe that Chromium unistaller doesn't remove this folder content.
I suggest you to rename this folder with another name, let's say
 /home/peter/.config/xxxchromium/ 
this should force Chromium to create a fresh configuration folder ;)
I hope that this suggestion will help you!

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I tried that as well with no luck (To google-chrome, though). "you mean Chromium, don't you?" I actually mean google-chrome: https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html

Comment: I added "Google" to the title for clarification