# Chrome doesn't autologin on the sites I have checked "Remember me" on reboot

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome

Earlier I had to log in just once in, for example, Gmail and StackExchange sites if I checked "Remember me". Chrome would remember it and wouldn't ask me to log in again after rebooting.

I forgot my password and reset in recovery. Then I removed autologin from `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`

I think these are the only changes I made. Has it got to do with anything with Login-Keyring/Other-Keyrings?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Chrome does not keep cookies.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/41679/google-chrome-does-not-keep-cookies)

Comment: @George Don't think it's a duplicate of that one. I checked my cookies. Stackoverflow cookies are present there.

Comment: Did you try the other answer(s)?

Comment: I actually had something like this happen to me. I tried all the cookie clearings, reinstalls, etc, and nothing worked. It turned out I just had to wait for the keyring to unlock itself before running Chrome. I judge it by waiting until icons show up on my desktop, but it'll be different for you. Try waiting 5 minutes after logging in before opening Chrome and see if it works.